# ExternalInterface to call a function belongs to a JS object

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm using `ExternalInterface` in my AS3 project to do some stuff via Javascript, but now I need to use it to call some function belong to an object.

Something like this (AS3):

```
ExternalInterface.call("VIEWER.loadComplete");
```

JS code:

```
var VIEWER = {
    loadComplete: function(){
        $('#'+this.maindiv).children('.mask').hide();
        $('#'+this.viewer).css({
            width:      '640px', 
            height:     '480px',
            overflow:   ''
        });
    }
}
```

This isn't working in Chrome (only works in Firefox, and I don't know why either). Can someone clarify me in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem adding the following to my SWF object embed in HTML:

```
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
```

Now my SWF is able to call `ExternalInterface` (even in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with the Chrome version of the player, the rules you set in Flash Player global settings are not used / loaded by this player. So you always get sandbox security errors and external interfaces dont work.

You need to go on the chrome plugin page `chrome://plugins/` and desactivate the `PPAPI` (Pepper API, Chrome version) version of the flash Player and enable only the `NPAPI` version (classical).

Comment: Thanks for the info, RafH. I really need to use ExternalInterface, so what can I do? Do you think there is an alternative?

Comment: You can use ExternallInterface, it works with PPAPI player when you use http:// to access your content. The problem is only when accessing locally (file://).

Comment: I'm still having the problem even when I use http access. Any ideas? :(